# Turn off download option on Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox

I have some .pdf files on dropbox that are publicly shared. Is there a way to disable the download option so that they are only viewable on dropbox, but *not* downloadable to one's desktop?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible.

*(Also it makes little sense to disable downloads, if they can view on Dropbox, it's trivial to save it)*

Answer (score 0):

Have to disagree with Sathya.  It does make sense in a number of cases.  For example, I might provide an Excel spreadsheet so that everyone can see a forecast within Dropbox but disable downloading so that they cannot see the personnel data within the spreadsheet.  Yes, I know that you can password protect the spreadsheet, or that you can save the spreadsheet as a pdf to limit viewing.  However, disabling downloading and just allowing views would be a simple way of distribution without full access.

Comment: This should be a comment.